# Sources for importance of achdus

Tags: sources-mekorot

What are some good sources of the importance (and benefits) of achdus to encourage people to work on improving it?  (Preferably in English)

Comment: Tower of Bavel -one of my first lessons in childhood

Answer (score 3):

Firstly the importance of achdus:

[Succah 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.45b.9?lang=bi):

> רַבִּי לֵוִי אוֹמֵר, כְּתָמָר: מָה תָּמָר זֶה אֵין לוֹ אֶלָּא לֵב אֶחָד, אַף יִשְׂרָאֵל אֵין לָהֶם אֶלָּא לֵב אֶחָד לַאֲבִיהֶם שֶׁבַּשָּׁמַיִם
>
> Rabbi Levi says: It is like a date palm. Just as the date palm has only one heart, (as branches do not grow from its trunk but rather the trunk rises and branches emerge only at the top,) so too, the Jewish people have only one heart directed toward their Father in Heaven.

In other words, when the Jewish people are united we form a much stronger channel towards G-d.

Along this thinking, refer to the [Sifrei Devarim 346](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.346.1?lang=bi)

> (ה) ויהי בישורון מלך, **כשישראל שוים בעצה אחת מלמטה שמו הגדול משתבח מלמעלה** שנאמר ויהי בישורון מלך, אימתי בהתאסף ראשי עם ואין אסיפה אלא ראשי עם שנאמר (במדבר כה ד) ויאמר ה' אל משה קח את כל ראשי העם. דבר אחר כשהנשיא מושיב זקנים בישיבה של מטה שמו הגדול משתבח מלמעלה שנאמר ויהי בישורון מלך אימתי בהתאסף ראשי עם ואין אסיפה אלא זקינים שנאמר (במדבר יא טז) אספה לי שבעים איש מזקני ישראל.
>
> (Devarim 33:5) "And He was a King in Yeshurun": **When Israel are of one counsel below, His great name is exalted above**, viz. "And He was a King in Yeshurun" — When? "when the heads of the people gathered." And there is no "gathering" but that of the elders, as it is written (Bamidbar 11:16) "Gather unto Me seventy men from the elders of Israel."

This concept is amplified by the [Sfas Emes](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefat_Emet%2C_Genesis%2C_Noach.16.4?vhe=Sefat_emet,_Piotrk%C3%B3w,_1905-1908&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) when explaining Migdal Bavel (The Tower of Babel):

> שבאמת כח האחדות גדול מאוד לעורר כח השורש מן השמים.דור הפלגה התאספו כולם ולא עלתה בידם
>
> That in truth, the power of unity is really great to awaken the power of the root from heaven.

Another crucial element of maintaining achdus is both the individual and national sense of responsibility it creates for fellow Jews:

[Shevuos 39a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.39a.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וכל עבירות שבתורה מכל העולם לא והכתיב (ויקרא כו, לז) וכשלו איש באחיו איש בעון אחיו מלמד **שכל ישראל ערבים זה בזה**
>
> And with regard to all of the other transgressions in the Torah, is punishment not exacted from the entire world? But isn’t it written: “And they shall stumble one upon another” (Leviticus 26:37)? This verse is homiletically interpreted to mean that they shall stumble spiritually, one due to the iniquity of another, which teaches that **the entire Jewish people are considered guarantors for one another**. Apparently, any transgression makes the entire world liable to be punished.

Now the benefits:

**1) A reason for our longevity**

In times of trouble, it is when we group together, we are able to withstand the trials and tribulations and emerge as one.

[Midrash Tanchuma - Nitzavim 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Nitzavim.1.1?lang=bi)

> אַתֶּם נִצָּבִים הַיּוֹם. זֶה שֶׁאָמַר הַכָּתוּב: הָפוֹךְ רְשָׁעִים וְאֵינָם, וּבֵית צַדִּיקִים יַעֲמֹד (משלי יב, ז). כָּל זְמַן שֶׁהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מִסְתַּכֵּל בְּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶם שֶׁל רְשָׁעִים וּמְהַפֵּךְ בָּהֶם, אֵין לָהֶם תְּקוּמָה. הָפַךְ בְּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶם שֶׁל דּוֹר הַמַּבּוּל, לֹא הָיְתָה לָהֶם תְּקוּמָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיִּמַּח אֶת כָּל הַיְקוּם (בראשית ז, כג). הָפַךְ בְּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶם שֶׁל אַנְשֵׁי סְדוֹם, וְלֹא הָיְתָה בָהֶן תְּקוּמָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיַּהֲפֹךְ אֶת הֶעָרִים הָאֵל (שם יט, כה). הָפַךְ בְּמַעֲשֵׂיהֶם שֶׁל מִצְרִים, וְלֹא הָיְתָה לָהֶן תְּקוּמָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: לֹא נִשְׁאַר בָּהֶם עַד אֶחָד (שמות יד, כח). הָפַךְ בַּמַּעֲשֶׂה שֶׁל בָּבֶל וְלֹא הָיְתָה לָהּ תְּקוּמָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וְהִכְרַתִּי לְבָבֶל שֵׁם וּשְׁאָר וְנִין וָנֶכֶד (ישעיה יד, כב). וְעַל כֻּלָּם אָמַר דָּוִד, שָׁם נָפְלוּ פּוֹעֲלֵי אָוֶן וְגוֹ' (תהלים לו, יג). **אֲבָל יִשְׂרָאֵל, נוֹפְלִין וְעוֹמְדִין**. וְכֵן הוּא אוֹמֵר, אַל תִּשְׂמְחִי אוֹיַבְתִּי לִי כִּי נָפַלְתִּי קָמְתִּי וְגוֹ' (מיכה ז, ח).
>
> (Deut. 29:9:) “You are standing today.” This text is related (to Prov. 12:7), “The wicked are overturned (rt.: hpk) and are no more, but the house of the righteous shall stand.” Every time that the Holy One, blessed be He, looks at the works of the wicked and turns (rt.: hpk) them over (examines them), there is no recovery for them. He turned over the works of the generation of the flood, and there was no recovery for them, as stated (in Gen. 7:23), “And he wiped out all living things.” He turned over the works of the Sodomites, and there was no recovery for them, as stated (in Gen. 19:25), “And he overturned those cities.” He turned over the works of the Egyptians, and there was no recovery for them, as stated (in Exod. 14:28), “and not so much as one of them remained.” He turned over the works of Babylon, and there was no recovery for them, as stated (in Is. 14:22), “and from Babylon I will cut off name, remnant, offspring, and posterity.” Moreover, David has said about all of them (in Ps. 36:13), “There the evildoers have fallen; they are thrust down and cannot rise.” **When Israel falls, however, it stands up [again]**, as stated (in Micah 7:8), “Rejoice not over me, O my enemy; when I fall, I shall arise….”

The text then famously concludes:

> **וְהָיָה לְךָ ה' לְאוֹר עוֹלָם (ישעיה ס, יט). אֵימָתַי, בִּזְמַן שֶׁתִּהְיוּ כֻּלְּכֶם אֲגֻדָּה אַחַת**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: חַיִּים כֻּלְּכֶם הַיּוֹם (דברים ד, ד). בְּנֹהַג שֶׁבָּעוֹלָם, **אִם נוֹטֵל אָדָם אֲגֻדָּה שֶׁל קָנִים, שֶׁמָּא יָכֹל לְשָׁבְרָם בְּבַת אַחַת. וְאִלּוּ נוֹטֵל אַחַת אַחַת, אֲפִלּוּ תִּינוֹק מְשַׁבְּרָן. וְכֵן אַתְּ מוֹצֵא שֶׁאֵין יִשְׂרָאֵל נִגְאֲלִין עַד שֶׁיִּהְיוּ כֻּלָּן אֲגֻדָּה אַחַת**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: בַּיָּמִים הָהֵמָּה וּבָעֵת הַהִיא נְאֻם ה' יָבֹאוּ בְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וּבְנֵי יְהוּדָה יַחְדָּו וְגוֹ' (ירמיה נ, ד). כְּשֶׁהֵן אֲגוּדִים, מְקַבְּלִין פְּנֵי שְׁכִינָה.
>
> Although you have darkness, the Holy One, blessed be He, is going to shine on you with light eternal, as stated (in Is. 60:19), **“For the Lord shall be your everlasting light.” When? When you all become one group**, as stated (in Deut. 4:4), “are all alive today.” According to universal custom, **if one takes a group of reeds, will he be able to break them at one stroke! But if he takes them one by one, even an infant can break them. So also you find that Israel was not redeemed until they became one group**, as stated (in Jer. 50:4), “’In those days and at that time,’ says the Lord,’ the children of Israel, they and the children of Judah, shall come together.’” When they are united, they shall welcome the face of the Divine Presence.

**2) It brings the ultimate redemption**

[Bereishis Rabbah 98:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.98.2?vhe=Daat_Bereshit_Rabbah&lang=bi)

> אמר להון: תהיו כלכון אסיפה אחת, הה"ד (יחזקאל לז): ואתה בן אדם, קח לך עץ אחד וכתוב עליו וגו' לבני ישראל וגו' חבירו כתיב, **נעשו בני ישראל אגודה אחת, התקינו עצמכם לגאולה**.
>
> He said to them: ‘You shall all be one assembly.’ That is what is written: “You, Son of man, take for you one piece of wood, and write on it: [For Judah] and for the children of Israel [his companions]” (Ezekiel 37:16) – it is written “his companion” – **the children of Israel became a single group. Prepare yourselves for redemption.**

[similar to the Tanchuma cited above - שֶׁאֵין יִשְׂרָאֵל נִגְאֲלִין עַד שֶׁיִּהְיוּ כֻּלָּן אֲגֻדָּה אַחַת]

**3) It protect Klal Yisroel - even when not worthy**

[Midrash Tanchuma - Siman 18](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Shoftim.18.1?vhe=Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> שֶׁבְּשָׁעָה שֶׁיִּשְׂרָאֵל עוֹשִׂין חֲבוּרָה אַחַת, אֲפִילוּ עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה בֵּינֵיהֶם, אֵין מִדַּת הַדִּין נוֹגַעַת בָּהֶם
>
> At the time that Israel makes itself into one group, the trait of strict judgement does not reach them, even [if there is] idolatry amongst them.

*To be continued...*

Comment: Yasher koach on a response with so many examples!

Comment: Absolute pleasure! Shkoiach on a great question!